# Получить координаты по названию объектов в React Components

Tags: reactjs, yandex-maps-api

подскажите, имеется пустой state массив для установки в него координат, имеется массив с названием объектов, адресов. Пытаюсь получить координаты и далее вывести их на карту, но что то не выходит, где ошибка:

```
 const geoplace = [
   'Москва','Сочи','Самара'
]
export class Mappy extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            coordinates:[]
        }
    }


    geocode (ymaps) {
        geoplace.map((geo,index)=>{
            const temp = ymaps.geocode(geo)
            temp.then(result=>this.setState({coordinates:result.GeoObject.get(0).geometry.getCoordinates()}))
        })

    }

     render(){

        return(

            <div>

            <YMaps>      
                <Map defaultState={mapState} onLoad={ymaps => this.geocode(ymaps)} modules={['geocode']}>

                {this.state.coordinates?
                    this.state.coordinates.map((coord,index)=><Placemark key = {index} geometry{coord}/>)
                 :null
                } 

                </Map>          
            </YMaps>

     </div>

        )
    }
```

Comment: Что получилось в результате, что ожидаете? Что именно не выходит? Дополните ваш вопрос конкретной проблемой. Что в переменной `mapState`? Правильный объект с проперти `center` и `zoom`?

Comment: Да какие то чудеса, сначало в state заностлся object array с координатами, но отрисовываться метки на карте не хотели вылетала ошибка desirilez что ли, а потом вообще по нулям. Вот необходимо что бы на карту метки ставились, по названиям объектов, адресу итд. Да, в mapstate хранится координаты того места, где я хочу видеть свои метки.

Answer (score 0):

```
onMapClick(event) {
        this.setState({coords: event.get("coords")});
        console.log(this.state.coords)
    }
```